# Call a report from other report

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I need to create a menu for 4 reports I have, what I want to do is that when you press the name of the report it will show you the report.

Answer (score 0):

Just create an "action" on your text box

[Add a Drillthrough Action on a Report](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/add-a-drillthrough-action-on-a-report-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15)